# Simple sorting by number script, 3 lines, doesn't sort last few li's correctly, why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

http://jsfiddle.net/nicktheandroid/6BAfH/1/

The list-elements are sorted accordingly by the number in their span. Why is it that the last few numbers are out of order? I'm confused.

**Jquery**

```
function sortEm(a,b){
  return parseInt($('span', a).text()) < parseInt($('span', b).text()) ? 1 : -1;
}

$('li').sort(sortEm).prependTo($('ul#test'));
```

**HTML**

```
<ul id="test">

    <li> Cups
        <span>12</span>
    </li>

    <li> Plates
        <span>18</span>
    </li>

    <li> Forks
        <span>03</span>
    </li>

    <li> Knives
        <span>08</span>
    </li>

    <li> Bowls
        <span>55</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: FYI: you could use `return parseInt($('span', b).text()) - parseInt($('span', a).text())`

Comment: Use parseFloat: http://jsfiddle.net/6BAfH/3/

Comment: Stefan, it still requires the radix though, so your code gets me the same error than mine does. I think parseFloat is the way to go.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Welcome to the world of octal numbers.

> If the input string begins with "0", radix is eight (octal). This feature is non-standard, and some implementations deliberately do not support it (instead using the radix 10).  For this reason always specify a radix when using parseInt.

Use the radix to base 10 with [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

```
parseInt($('span', a).text(), 10)
```